# determinant definition using nested summation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, summation, permutations, determinant

While reading up on the linear algebra used in dynamics, I came across a definition of a matrix determinant that I'm still trying to figure out. The definition is stated like this:
$$\det{\bf A}=\frac 16\sum_{i=1}^{3}\sum_{j=1}^{3}\sum_{k=1}^{3}\sum_{r=1}^{3}\sum_{s=1}^{3}\sum_{t=1}^{3}e_{ijk}e_{rst}A_{ir}A_{js}A_{kt}$$
$$\text{where:}$$
$$e_{ijk}=1\text{ if }(i,j,k)\text{ is an even permutation of }(1,2,3)(i.e.~e_{123}=e_{312}=1)$$
$$e_{ijk}=-1\text{ if }(i,j,k)\text{ is an odd permutation of }(1,2,3)(i.e.~e_{321}=e_{213}=-1)$$
$$e_{ijk}=0\text{ if any two of }i,~j,~k\text{ are equal }(i.e.~e_{112}=0)$$
In the reading, this definition is given for the determinant of any 3 x 3 matrix. Although I am not experienced yet with linear algebra, I'm familiar with 3 x 3 determinants and the process of finding them. However, I'm stumped when trying to understand this formal definition. I vaguely understand the idea of permutation products and their representation in the Leibniz definition, and I can correlate that the definition of $e$ as an alternating symbol satisfies this permutation aspect.

I suppose what I mean is that I understand what this definition is saying, but I don't understand the specific mechanics by which it is saying it. I get that each sum represents a permutation of some row or column, but why the usage of variables like $r,s,t$? Are they just arbitrary for the sake of summation? Why the $\frac 16$ coefficient? I also just do not understand the low level math that is happening within each summation. Is this definition just a representation of every single permutation inside of some 3 x 3 matrix and it's not really necessary to understand the determinant function at that low of a level? Any help would be appreciated.

If it helps, the specific location of this definition is in A.J.M. Spencer's "*Continuum Mechanics*", figure (2.8).

Comment: This looks like an unbelievably convoluted way to write the [Leibniz formula](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_determinants) for the determinant of a $3\times 3$ matrix. Hopefully knowing where your weird formula comes from can somewhat help you.

Comment: Leibniz's definition is $\sum_{\sigma}\operatorname{sign}(\sigma)a_{1,\sigma(1)}a_{2,\sigma(2)}a_{3,\sigma(3)}$. The row indices are fixed. In your book's definition, the row indices are also permuted. Thus each product $a_{1x}a_{2y}a_{3z}$ is counted six times in your book's definition as $a_{ir}a_{js}a_{kt}$ for six times with $(i,r,j,s,k,t)$ being $$\{(1,x,2,y,3,z),\ (1,x,3,z,2,y),\ (2,y,3,z,1,x),$$
$$(2,y,1,x,3,z),\ (3,z,1,x,2,y),\ (3,z,2,y,1,x)\}$$

Comment: Spencer should be ashamed for presenting this as a definition.

Comment: This looks like the expression for the determinant [using Levi Cevita symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_symbol#Applications_and_examples).